# sqlcommand not properly ended

Tags: java, oracle, servlets, dao

i cannot update my form. it says that my sql is not properly ended. this is my updateCust of custDao. The ResultSet seem not be used. it seems to direct go to catch exception.

```
 public void updateCust(Customer cust) {
  try {
    Statement statement = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("UPDATE CUSTOMER "
            + "SET custName =        '" + cust.getCustName() + "',"
            + "custAdd = '" + cust.getCustAdd() + "',"
            + "custRegion = '" + cust.getCustRegion() + "' "
            + "custHandphoneNo = '" + cust.getCustHandphoneNo() + "' "
            + "custPhoneNo = '" + cust.getCustPhoneNo() + "' "
            + "custEmail = '" + cust.getCustEmail() + "' "
            + "WHERE cust_id = " + cust.getCust_id());
  } catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println("problem update");
  }
}
```

this is my form after retrieve data from searchbox

```html
<form action="CustomerController?action=edit" method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td style:width="30px"><h3 class="templatemo-gold">ID Number: </h3></td>
            <td style:width="70px">><input type="text" name="cust_id" id="cust_id" value="${custDetail.cust_id}"/> <br/><br/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><h3 class="templatemo-gold">Name: </h3></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="custName" id="custName" size="50" value="${custDetail.custName}"/> <br/><br/>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><h3 class="templatemo-gold">Address: </h3></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="custAdd" size="50" value="${custDetail.custAdd}"
                    /><br/><br/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><h3 class="templatemo-gold">Region: </h3></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="custRegion" id="custRegion" size="50" value="${custDetail.custRegion}"
                    /><br/><br/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
        <tr><h3 class="templatemo-gold">Handphone No: </h3></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="custHandphoneNo" id="custHandphoneNo" size="50"
                       value="${custDetail.custHandphoneNo}"
                    /><br/><br/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><h3 class="templatemo-gold">Phone No: </h3></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="custPhoneNo" id="custPhoneNo" size="50" value="${custDetail.custPhoneNo}"
                    /><br/><br/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><h3 class="templatemo-gold">Email: </h3></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="custEmail" id="custEmail" size="50" value="${custDetail.custEmail}"
                    /><br/><br/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update" action="CustomerController?action=edit"
                       class="btn text-uppercase templatemo-btn templatemo-info-btn"></td>
            <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Delete"
                       class="btn text-uppercase templatemo-btn templatemo-info-btn"></td>
        </tr>

    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Absolute first thing to do: stop building SQL like that. Use a `PreparedStatement` with parameterized SQL. Your current approach is hugely vulnerable to SQL Injection Attacks.

Comment: can you print out the sql query before executing it? chances are it's missing a quote or sth. And also use PreparedStatement like Jon Skeet says :)

Comment: how to use preparedStatement to executeQuery?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing comma after end quote on these lines:

```
+ "custRegion = '"+cust.getCustRegion()+"' "
+ "custHandphoneNo = '"+cust.getCustHandphoneNo()+"' "
+ "custPhoneNo = '"+cust.getCustPhoneNo()+"' "
```

And please use [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) instead

Answer (score 0):

You can use `OraclePreparedStatement` and bind variable using "names"

```
 OraclePreparedStatement statement = (OraclePreparedStatement)con.prepareStatement("UPDATE CUSTOMER "
                                        + " SET custName = :custName, "
                                        + " custAdd = :custAdd, "
                                        + " custRegion = :custRegion, "
                                        + " custHandphoneNo = :custHandphoneNo , "
                                        + " custPhoneNo = :custPhoneNo , "
                                        + " custEmail = :custEmail "
                                        + " WHERE cust_id = :cust_id ");
```

Bind the variables.

```
statement.setStringAtName("custName",cust.getCustName());
statement.setStringAtName("custAdd",cust.getCustAdd());
statement.setStringAtName("custRegion",cust.getCustRegion());
statement.setStringAtName("custHandphoneNo",cust.getCustHandphoneNo());
statement.setStringAtName("custPhoneNo",cust.getCustPhoneNo());
statement.setStringAtName("custEmail",cust.getCustEmail());
statement.setStringAtName("cust_id",cust.cust_id());
```

Execute the Query

```
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery();
```